# Parsing Custom Created MIDI Files in Android

Tags: java, android, midi

I have re-created a `MIDI` file without altering any of its `Meta` events. I have merely added `SysEx (System Exclusive)` messages under each `note_on` and `note_off` event. I use [this](https://github.com/pdrogfer/MidiDroid) library to parse MIDI files and extract tracks in order to get the MIDI messages.

Following is some sample code that I have tried (I have the MIDI file inside the raw folder).

```
try {

    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mysamplemidifile);
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".mid");
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    IOUtils.copy(is, out);
    MidiFile midi = new MidiFile(tempFile);
    ArrayList<MidiTrack> tracks = midi.getTracks();
    MidiTrack sysExTrack = tracks.get(tracks.size() - 1);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Originally the total number of MIDI messages is ~2500. But the library is able to fetch only about 2300 MIDI messages. 
The `sysExTrack` variable contains the incompletely parsed `SysEx` data.

I am at a loss to understand what is going wrong here. Any help with the same is appreciated.

**Edit:**
The MIDI file gets parsed correctly in iOS.

Comment: Are you asking if your file is wrong, or if the library has a bug? How should anybody else know?

Comment: @CL. The same file gets parsed perfectly in iOS. So I guess, it's a bug in the library. I'll edit the question though. Thanks for the cue.